# How run headless angular2 e2e tests using protractor in vagrant ubuntu-16.04?

Tags: angular, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am running ubuntu-16.04 using Vagrant and need to run angular2 end-to-end (e2e) tests in a gui-less environment for continuous integration. After scouring the angular documentation I have failed to find even any mention of what seems like should be a common use case.

I have found a couple instruction sets coming close that utilize xvfb, but the lack of upfront documentation from angular on this makes me feel I am missing something obvious.

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/protractor-with-jenkins-and-headless-chrome-xvfb-setup/

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**Update** I answered the question below with two different working solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***XVFB Based Solution:***

**Standalone Selenium Server**

Below is a working solution that uses a standalone selenium server taken mainly from www.tothenew.com.

Installs:

```
#Provision Java JDK
sudo apt-get install default-jdk -y

#Provision Protractor
sudo npm install protractor -g

#Webdriver update
sudo webdriver-manager update

#Exposing chromedriver
sudo ln /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.29 /usr/bin/chromedriver

sudo apt-get install libxpm4 libxrender1 libgtk2.0-0 libnss3 libgconf-2-4 -y

#Provision Google Chrome
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y

sudo apt-get install xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf -y
sudo apt-get install xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable -y
sudo apt-get install imagemagick x11-apps dbus-x11 -y
```

Create script: /etc/init.d/selenium

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  echo -n                                             >   /etc/init.d/selenium
  echo '#!/bin/sh'                                    >>  /etc/init.d/selenium
  echo 'Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &'        >>  /etc/init.d/selenium
  echo '#disown $1'                                   >>  /etc/init.d/selenium
  echo 'export DISPLAY=:99'                           >>  /etc/init.d/selenium
  echo 'webdriver-manager start /dev/null 2>&1'       >>  /etc/init.d/selenium

  sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/selenium

SHELL
```

Update protactor.conf.js to use seleniumAddress:

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    directConnect: false,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
    },
    onPrepare() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

To Run:

1. run /etc/init.d/selenium
2. run ng e2e

**Protractor Starts Selenium Server**

Based on the suggestion from Sudharsan below is another working solution. In this case protractor starts selenium server.

Installs:

```
#Provision Java JDK
sudo apt-get install default-jdk -y

#Provision Protractor
sudo npm install protractor -g

#Webdriver update
sudo webdriver-manager update

#Exposing chromedriver
sudo ln /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.29 /usr/bin/chromedriver

#Provision Google Chrome
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y

#Provision xvfb
sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
sudo apt-get install -y  xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic  dbus-x11
```

Protractor config:

```
exports.config = {
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect: true,
    //getPageTimeout: 60000,  
    //allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
    },
    onPrepare() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

To Run:

```
xvfb-run -a -e /dev/stdout -s "-screen 0 2920x2580x24" ng e2e
```

**Running Unit Tests Against Chrome Also Works**

```
xvfb-run -a -e /dev/stdout -s "-screen 0 2920x2580x24" ng test --single-run
```

***Headless Chromium Solution:***

Chrome now has a headless option. xvfb no longer required. The xvfb installs can be omitted.

*karma*

```
browsers: ['ChromeCI'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeCI: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--remote-debugging-port=9222']
  }
},
```

*protractor*

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['no-sandbox', 'headless', 'disable-gpu']
  }
},
```

Test can then be running normally:

```
ng test
ng e2e
```

Comment: Info for anyone else coming here - for the headless chrome solution, sendkeys do not work. There is a known issue sendkeys & headless chrome.https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1772

Comment: @wizgot The sendKeys issue (requiring xvfb on *nix) is fixed in chromedriver 2.31, which you can build yourself from source. Currently it is also being prepared for general release.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, Just follow the below steps.

Step1: Install xvfb.

enter the below command in terminal to install xvfb and its dependencies,

```
 sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
 sudo apt-get install -y  xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic  dbus-x11
```

Thats it. Now you can trigger your protractor test using below command,

```
xvfb-run -a -e /dev/stdout -s "-screen 0 2920x2580x24" protractor config.js
```

Comment: Thanks Sudharsan. So I just use the default protractor config that uses Chrome and leave out the seleniumAddress? Can you perhaps include your protractor config for reference?

Comment: Just remove `seleniumAddress` key from the config file. Protractor will start selenium server by itself in XVFB buffer display.

Comment: Using your approach, I ran into these issues. 1) protractor indicated that I needed to run webdriver-manager update, 2) java was missing, 3) selenium couldn't find the Chrome binary. Once those were installed (see my install list above), I get this error: Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:4200/ : retries looking for angularexceeded. In my protractor conf I have {directConnect: true, baseUrl 'http://localhost:4200/', framework: 'jasmine', ...}

Comment: I added {getPageTimeout: 60000,  allScriptsTimeout: 500000} to protractor conf per the protractor doc on dealing with timeouts. But it didn't help. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If I run 'ng serve' in another session then the tests run and pass. Is this expected? Why doesn't protractor handle this?

Comment: Running 'ng e2e' instead of protractor solved the issue: xvfb-run -a -e /dev/stdout -s "-screen 0 2920x2580x24" ng e2e

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out docker as a lightweight solution: https://hub.docker.com/r/trion/ng-cli-e2e/
More detailed manual: https://hub.docker.com/r/trion/ng-cli/